# Вектор пары в C++

Tags: c++, vector

Здравствуйте,мне нужен вектор,в каждом элементе коорого хранится пара целых чисел.Вот мой код:

```
vector <pair<int,int> > g[2000];
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i){
    int a,b;
    cin >> a >> b ;
    g.push_back(make_pair(a,b));
}
```

У меня появляется ошибка:request for member "push_back" in "g" which is of non-class type "std::vector > 2000".
Скажите,пожалуйста,в чём моя ошибка?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле вполне информативное сообщение: вы создали *массив* (на 2000 элементов) вектров.

Расписываю подробнее: vector<> - шаблон, но для простоты будем считать что это класс. Если мы создаём объект класса то нужно писать

```
Class class(/*params*/);
```

Если в классе существует конструктор без параметров то `()` можно не указывать например так:

```
 Class class;
```

Когда вы пишите

```
Class class[10];
```

То компилятор это понимает как создать массив на 10 объектов класса `Class` с констуктором по умолчанию (без параметров). Если конструктора без параметров нет - то произойдёт ошибка компиляции. Пример:

```
class C{
    public: C(int a){}; 
    //C(){};    
};

int main() {
    C a[5];
    return 0;
}
```

У *массива* нет метода `push_back` что и приводит к ошибке компиляции.
Я не знаю что именно вы хотите, поэтому либо пишите

```
g[0].push_back(make_pair(a,b));
```

либо объявлейте

```
vector <pair<int,int> > g;
```

либо, если вам важен размер, то используйте что-то типо

```
vector <pair<int,int> > g;
...
g.resize(2000); //g.reserve(2000);
```

Comment: Мне не нужно,чтобы в каждом элементе был вектор пар.Мне нужен один вектор,каждый элемент которого пара. @pavel

Comment: 2 или 3 вариант.

Comment: Извините,а почему неправильно моё объявление? @pavel

Comment: @VladslavRublevskii вы массив векторов. Вроде бы даже написал в ответе. Попробую чуть подробнее написать.

Comment: @ pavel Я понял,спасибо Вам.Последний вопрос,я использовал ваше объявление,но после этого у меня появилась ошиба:Segmentation error

Comment: @VladslavRublevskii это весь код? Или ещё что-то есть?

Comment: @pavel "Если в классе существует конструктор без параметров то () можно не указывать" в случае отсутствия параметров, пустые скобки вовсе нельзя указывать, иначе получится объявление функции.

Answer (score 0):

Можно пробовать так:

```
vector <pair<int, int> > g;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;

        cin >> a >> b;
        g.push_back(make_pair(a, b));
}
```